# ASP.Net - Word / Excel / PPT online modification

Tags: asp.net

We have ASP.Net Application where user can upload Word, Excel & PPT file. When user clicks on any uploaded document we open up it with local machine viewer.

what we need when document of Word / Excel / PPT is opened - user can be able to modify the document and able to directly SAVE it on the server.

What are the BEST way to do this (GoogleDocs OR Office 365)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to program something to do this, or which software package to go with? Also, you should accept a few more of your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office 365 and Google Docs are the two main players in online office suites right now. These two suites provide fundamentally different experiences for end users. Office 365 is primarily meant to tie into traditional, locally installed copies of Microsoft Office—and that’s where your users are likely to do most of their work. Google Docs is all about working in browsers—you can import and export Office files, but web apps are Google’s focus.

Comparisons link: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/cloud-computing2/office-365-google-docs-enduser-perspective-140011